# DWScript basetype efficiency

Tags: delphi, dwscript

The limited amount basetypes in DWScript can be very convenient, but doesn't it add a lot of overhead. Considering that integers are Int64, this should be quite a bit of overhead when you're working with byte values for example. Does DWScript optimize for this internally? If not, is there a way to use language extensions to add other basetypes, such as `Byte`?

In the event that this would cause problems with type inference, if it's possible to handle this in language extensions, inference for integer values could be deferred to the main `Integer` type or handled by the extension to select the smallest fitting datatype for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DWS uses Variants as an internal base type for storing all values.  Since a Variant is significantly larger than a Byte, there's really nothing to be gained by using the Byte type in scripts.

Comment: Indeed Variant is 16 bytes. There is a long term plan to wean the engine off Variants, but that's still in the future. Smaller time could be worse introducing then.